# How to create testable code using .Net IO classes?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, tdd, inversion-of-control, base-class-library

I want to create unit testable code that mocks out the calls to the .Net System.IO classes, so I can really unit test instead of depending on the filesystem.
I am using the [SystemWrapper](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/) classes to wrap around the BCL classes.

I am trying to get a simple example working to see whether a file exists.

The problem I am having is that injecting the dependency in the class doesn't work because instantiating the dependency (through [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/)) requires knowing what constructor parameter to pass, which won't be available at that time, also there is no default constructor.

sample code:

```
// don't want to create dependency here like so
//IFileInfoWrap fileInfoWrap = new FileInfoWrap(filename);

// using service locator (anti-pattern?!) since it can't be 
// injected in this class
var fileInfoWrap = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IFileInfoWrap>(
    new ExplicitArguments(new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"fileName", filename}
    }));

Console.WriteLine("File exists? {0}",  fileInfoWrap.Exists);
```

What I don't like is that the dependency is not injected, ObjectFactory should not be here (but I see no other way of creating this).
The ExplicitArguments makes it messy and the argument-name is a magic-string.

For me to get this to work  StructureMap config class needs to know explict which constructor I want to use ( I just started with StructureMap so this might not be the right way to set it up):

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.AssembliesFromPath(".");
        scan.RegisterConcreteTypesAgainstTheFirstInterface();
        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
    });

    // use the correct constructor (string instead of FileInfo)
    x.SelectConstructor(() => new FileInfoWrap(null as string));

    // setting the value of the constructor
    x.For<IFileInfoWrap>()
        .Use<FileInfoWrap>()
        .Ctor<string>("fileName")
        .Is(@".");
});
```

Does anyone found a better solution to create testable code against the System.IO classes?
I know part of the problem is in the design of the System.IO classes.

Comment: SystemWrapper contains mostly extremely leaky abstractions. It'd be much simpler and easier to model IO against Streams, TextWriter, TextReader, etc. These classes already are abstract, completely removing the need for SystemWrapper.

Comment: Another vote for streams

Comment: My findings with the SystemWrapper are that it seems to be a nice wrapper with interfaces, however its still a dead end because of the way the original classes work.

For instance returning an array of FileInfo objects can't be mocked properly. Rolling my own more simplified wrapper which doesn't have to mimic the existing classes, while being more work does lead to a workable solution IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An approach I've used very successfully is to roll my own proxy types for the types found in `System.IO` and other parts of the FCL. E.g. I want to take a dependency on `System.IO.File`. I create a library called `System.IO.Proxies` and add a concrete type `File` and an interface `IFile`. The interface `IFile` exposes members equivalent to all those which I require from `System.IO.File` and the concrete type implements those members by doing nothing other than forwarding method calls to `System.IO.File`. `System.IO.Proxies` is excluded from unit testing and code coverage. In my consuming assembly, I take a dependeny only on `System.IO.Proxies` and, specifically, I only take a dependency on `IFile`. This way I can mock this dependency easily and attain 100% code coverage for my consuming assembly.

(Note that this is a tailored version of my [more general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8100946/49241) to a previous question.)

Comment: Yes, that is the way I ended up also.

One could delegate the call to e.g. System.IO.FileInfo to a separate class.

Rolling your own proxy does require creating proxy for each class which might be quite some work, of course it can grow together with the needed functionality from the BCL class.
Also when other types (FileInfo) are returned, all the required attributes should be created in the proxy (Name, FullName, Length).

One would think this problem would be 'solved' already avoiding the proxying for everyone.

Comment: Used the same approach quite successfully. Usually you don't need all methods/properties/events of a class like _File_. And for the handful you do need it's really easy to write such wrappers.